How can I authenticate my application with a REST API?
In my company, we are working on a monolithic application composed of several elements:

Frontend: user interface,
Backend: AJAX request management and server-side form validation,
Task daemon: recurring process that runs at regular intervals.
Recently, I developed a REST API to centralize certain functionalities, enabling our customers to access them via external scripts.

We now want to evolve our application so that it gradually consumes this REST API. However, I'm faced with an authentication problem: I don't know what method to adopt to allow our application to access the API.
Currently:
The REST API uses manually generated API keys, as access is restricted to specific users.
The application, on the other hand, uses PHP sessions to manage authentication.
Here are my questions:

Should I generate API keys for all our users to enable API access from the frontend?
Would it make more sense to set up a specific authentication method for the frontend of our application, separate from the current API keys?

Below is a simplified diagram of our architecture:

I'm a bit lost on this subject and would welcome any suggestions or feedback. Thanks in advance for your help.

create a user a sign up & login page in frontend.
sign up -> save username & hashed password in DB (with other required details)
Login -> validate hashed password from db whether it is matching or not and generate a JWT token with required fields (for example, name, email and etc. don't encode sensitive info like password) response to frontend.
for each API request send this token to backend with API request header, validate this token in backend first, else throw unauthorized.
Learn more details about JWT token and its usage here

@MuhammedAliJouharA Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that I already have an authentication method that uses the API key system for the REST API. And if I apply what you're telling me, that would mean I'd have to take two authentication methods into account. Wouldn't that be a bit cumbersome?

undersood, why can't you use same token method in frontend as well. make sure to set some limits for the usage for each tokens, so that sharing of token will consume external users usage limit

@MuhammedAliJouharA What do you mean by using the same token method? Do you mean that instead of using static, non-expandable API keys, I should go through expandable and generatable token generation by authenticating with credentials?
